# django:Model get all User except one user with his user id

Tags: django, django-models

Is there any method of django model.object to get all the users from User model except one user with his id?

Comment: `User.objects.exclude(pk=my_pk)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
User.objects.exclude(pk=my_pk)
```

As [Willem Van Onsem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67579/willem-van-onsem) said or if you want to exclude multiples Users

```
User.objects.exclude(id__in=my_pk_list)
```

You can find information about QuerySet filters [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters)

Comment: Thanks man. It was useful as well.